# How to specify a traceset in OSL

Tags: rendering, osl

In the OSL spec, there is a an optional parameter in a trace call for a 'traceset'.

I would like to restrict a trace to only hit the same object. The solution I have right now is to get the object name and test the trace object name after it hits like this:

```
// start OSL code fragment
string thisobjname = "";
getattribute("geom:name",thisobjname);
int hit = trace(P, 
           ((_var_42 - 0.5) * 2.0), 
           );
string hitobjname = "";
getmessage("trace","geom:name",hitobjname);
if( hit && hitobjname==thisobjname)
           printf("trace hit the same object");
// end OSL code fragment
```

I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
// start OSL code fragment
string thisobjname = "";
getattribute("geom:name",thisobjname);
int hit = trace(P, 
           ((_var_42 - 0.5) * 2.0), 
           "traceset", thisobjname
           );
string hitobjname = "";
getmessage("trace","geom:name",hitobjname);
if( hit)
           printf("trace hit the same object");
// end OSL code fragment
```

How does the 'traceset' need to be formatted to work? Is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have traced this back to the OSL code where the 'traceset' is accepted and passed out to the compiled 'oso' file. This is further passed to Cycles to be executed and does indeed include the 'traceset' string.

However, on picking through the Cycles source code I came across the only reference to 'traceset' in the following function (trace) :

```
bool OSLRenderServices::trace(TraceOpt &options, OSL::ShaderGlobals *sg,
    const OSL::Vec3 &P, const OSL::Vec3 &dPdx,
    const OSL::Vec3 &dPdy, const OSL::Vec3 &R,
    const OSL::Vec3 &dRdx, const OSL::Vec3 &dRdy)
{
    /* todo: options.shader support, maybe options.traceset */
    ShaderData *sd = (ShaderData *)(sg->renderstate);

    /* setup ray */
    Ray ray;

    ray.P = TO_FLOAT3(P);
    ray.D = TO_FLOAT3(R);
    ray.t = (options.maxdist == 1.0e30f)? FLT_MAX: options.maxdist - options.mindist;
    ray.time = sd->time;

    if(options.mindist == 0.0f) {
        /* avoid self-intersections */
        if(ray.P == sd->P) {
            bool transmit = (dot(sd->Ng, ray.D) < 0.0f);
            ray.P = ray_offset(sd->P, (transmit)? -sd->Ng: sd->Ng);
        }
    }
    else {
        /* offset for minimum distance */
        ray.P += options.mindist*ray.D;
    }

    /* ray differentials */
    ray.dP.dx = TO_FLOAT3(dPdx);
    ray.dP.dy = TO_FLOAT3(dPdy);
    ray.dD.dx = TO_FLOAT3(dRdx);
    ray.dD.dy = TO_FLOAT3(dRdy);

    /* allocate trace data */
    OSLTraceData *tracedata = (OSLTraceData*)sg->tracedata;
    tracedata->ray = ray;
    tracedata->setup = false;
    tracedata->init = true;
    tracedata->sd.osl_globals = sd->osl_globals;

    /* raytrace */
    return scene_intersect(sd->osl_globals, ray, PATH_RAY_ALL_VISIBILITY, &tracedata->isect, NULL, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Note the comment `/* todo: options.shader support, maybe options.traceset */` - this is the only mention in Cycles source of 'traceset'. So, although the 'traceset' is passed into Cycles from the OSL shader it is not actually processed. This would seem to show that the 'traceset' option of the OSL 'trace' call has **not yet been implemented**.

Comment: This is great investigation! Which version of the  Blender was this source code from?

Comment: Thanks @EdTate. It was the latest Cycles and latest OSL so, presumably, all Blender versions.

Comment: still seems to be true, checked master branch in blender's official github mirror, [the todo comment is still there](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/f24ad274cb3002f380aa206c07ca564711bba089/intern/cycles/kernel/osl/services.cpp#L1616) and is still the only mention of `traceset`)